# I published my app on Google Play with a debug keystore

Tags: android, flutter, keystore, google-play-console, android-keystore

I'm working on a flutter mobile application, and when I publish a new release users don't see the update button on google play!
after searching the internet I find out that probably I published my app bundle using the debug Keystore.

do you think that this might be the problem?

PS: the app works fine on release mode.
[image]
https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not upload the app to the play store using the debug key. You must have signed the app bundle using the release key in order to submit the app to the play store.

There must be some other issues like lower build number in the pubspec.yaml

Comment: to be honest, i don't remember which commend I used back then because it was a long time ago when I was building the app even before I needed to publish it,i used it with firebase cloud messaging  for the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint

Comment: this is the app build number in pubspec.yaml : version: 1.0.1+13
I keep the 1.0.1+.. part and I change the other parent every single build : 13,14,15.....

Comment: what is the latest build number in play store and in your local ?

Comment: the last build is 1.0.1+13 in the play store should I change it to 1.0.2+14?

Comment: yes.  1.0.1+14 should also work

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just solved the problem, and it was with the version number :
 1.0.1+14 => didn't work 
 1.0.2+15 => work
anyways I will accept your ensure because you were right about the debug Keystore